# Integral involving the logarithm of a confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find the solution of the integral

\begin{align}
I =\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{\alpha+1}\left[ _{1}F_{1}(-m; \alpha +1;t)\right]^{2}\log\left[ _{1}F_{1}(-m; \alpha +1;t)\right]^{2}dt
\end{align}

where $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

My closest approach is thinking about the tabulated solution for 
\begin{align}
I_{2}=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\alpha + 1}e^{-t}\left[_{1}F_{1}(-m; \alpha +1;t)\right]^{2q}dt=\Gamma(\alpha)F_{A}^{(2q)} \begin{pmatrix},
    \alpha+2;-m,...,-m &  \\
     & ;1,...,1 \\
    \alpha+1,...,\alpha+1 &  
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

So

\begin{align}
I=\left.\frac{dI_{2}}{dq}\right\vert_{q=1}=\Gamma(\alpha)\frac{d}{dq}\left[F_{A}^{(2q)} \begin{pmatrix},
    \alpha+2;-m,...,-m &  \\
     & ;1,...,1 \\
    \alpha+1,...,\alpha+1 &  
  \end{pmatrix}\right]_{q=1},
\end{align}

but because q is supposse to be an integer number, I am not sure if this has sense and if it has, I do not know how to calculate it.

Comment: Why not back the differentiation up; i.e. differentiate under the integral sign and then try for the integration?

Comment: @rrogers I don't have very clear what do you mean, if I understood correct I made exactly this, but now my problem turns out to be the derivative of the Lauricella function. Could you explain your idea a little bit, please?

Comment: Differentiate under the integral sign in I2? i.e. Interchange.  Incidentally, I have found that the most effective approach to the original form is using a transform to the G-Function.  I don't know if it will work in this case and I don't have time right now.

Comment: I see, you end up with the ln(F..) again when you do that; probably how you got to equation 2 ?

Comment: @rrogers thanks for the try. I took equation 2 from a Srivastava paper ([this one](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Junesang_Choi/publication/324534333_The_Incomplete_Lauricella_Functions_of_Several_Variables_and_Associated_Properties_and_Formulas/links/5ad3e9350f7e9b28593605a9/The-Incomplete-Lauricella-Functions-of-Several-Variables-and-Associated-Properties-and-Formulas.pdf) equation 3.1)

Comment: Interesting paper; I pulled a copy down.  For your problem,I have thought about all that I know and  I don't have a clue.

Comment: @rrogers Thank you very much anyway!